# How to sum different factor values in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a sample that consists of 2787 rows and 259 columns.

To put this into context, it is a survey of how people in Spain perceive their current economic situation versus the one that was 6 months ago, carried out by a Spanish research institute, CIS.

Thus, I have a column (P3) with 5 answers: "better", "worse", "same", "don't know", and "don't answer". Also, I have another column (P19) with 2 options ("1" for males and "2" for females).

What I would like to get to know is how people rate their current versus past economic situation *based on* their gender (and plot this). In other words, to see how many males fare their situation "better", how many rate it "worse", and so on; and the same, with females.

To achieve this, I've been trying to run the following code:

```
CVSPastIndividualSituationMales<- aggregate(CIS$P3 ~ CIS$P19 == "1", CIS, sum)
CVSPastIndividualSituationFemales<- aggregate(CIS$P3 ~ CIS$P19 == "2", CIS, sum)


CurrentVSPastIndividualSituationMales<-ggplot(CIS,mapping=aes(x=CVSPastIndividualSituationMales))+geom_bar(fill="LightGreen")+xlab("Current VS Past Individual Situation for Males")
CurrentVSPastIndividualSituationFemales <-ggplot(CIS,mapping=aes(CVSPastIndividualSituationFemales))+geom_bar(fill="Green") + xlab("Current VS Past Individual Situation for Females")

ggarrange(CurrentVSPastIndividualSituationMales, CVSPastIndividualSituationFemales, ncol = 1, nrow = 1)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2787): x
Backtrace:
  1. ggpubr::ggarrange(...)
  2. purrr::map(...)
  3. ggpubr (local) .f(.x[[i]], ...)
  4. cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plotlist, ...)
  5. cowplot::align_plots(...)
     ...
 16. ggplot2 (local) by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
 17. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 18. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 19. ggplot2 (local) f(..., self = self)
 20. ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(evaled, n)
 Error in check_aesthetics(evaled, n) :
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I could possible get to the desired outcome?

Many thanks in advance!

P.S. Maybe a Dplyr solution might be available?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you map your aggregated datasets on the `x` aesthetic but pass the original dataframe to the `data` argument.

Using some fake data to mimic your real data I first reproduce your issue:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(123)

CIS <- data.frame(
  P19 = sample(c(1:2), 100, replace = TRUE),
  P3 = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

CVSPastIndividualSituationMales<- aggregate(CIS$P3 ~ CIS$P19 == "1", CIS, sum)
CVSPastIndividualSituationFemales<- aggregate(CIS$P3 ~ CIS$P19 == "2", CIS, sum)

CurrentVSPastIndividualSituationMales<-ggplot(CIS,mapping=aes(x=CVSPastIndividualSituationMales))+geom_bar(fill="LightGreen")+xlab("Current VS Past Individual Situation for Males")
CurrentVSPastIndividualSituationFemales <-ggplot(CIS,mapping=aes(CVSPastIndividualSituationFemales))+geom_bar(fill="Green") + xlab("Current VS Past Individual Situation for Females")

ggarrange(CurrentVSPastIndividualSituationMales, CVSPastIndividualSituationFemales, ncol = 1, nrow = 1)
#> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
#> Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
#> ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (100): x
```

While it's not a big task to fix this issue, overall you could achieve your result much easier with just `ggplot2` like so. First, `geom_bar` will already compute the counts by default. So we don't need aggregate. Second, instead of making two plots you could make one plot and use `facet_wrap` to get separate plots per gender. Finally you could map gender on `fill` and set your desired colors via `scale_fill_manual`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

CIS <- data.frame(
  P19 = sample(c(1:2), 100, replace = TRUE),
  P3 = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

CIS$P3 <- factor(CIS$P3, labels = c("better", "worse", "same", "don't know", "don't answer"))
CIS$P19 <- factor(CIS$P19, labels = c("Males", "Females"))

ggplot(CIS, aes(P3, fill = P19)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("LightGreen", "Green"), guide = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~P19) +
  xlab("Current VS Past Individual Situation")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much, @stefan! Your proposed ```ggplot2``` solution works just beautifully! Many thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using base R

```
set.seed(1000)
spain_data<-data.frame(P3=sample(c("better","worse","same","don't know","don't answer"),30,replace = TRUE),P19=sample(c(1,2),30,replace = TRUE)) 
male_pos<-which(spain_data$P19==1)
female_pos<-which(spain_data$P19==2)
male_response<-spain_data$P3[male_pos]
female_response<-spain_data$P3[female_pos]
bar<-barplot(rbind(table(male_response),table(female_response)),beside = TRUE,col = c("red","green"),ylim = c(0,( max(rbind(table(male_response),table(female_response)))+2)))
text(bar,rbind(table(male_response),table(female_response))+0.2,labels = as.character(rbind(table(male_response),table(female_response))))
legend("topleft",c("Male","Female"),fill=c("red","green"),bty = "n",cex=0.9)
```

If it is desired to generate separate barplots for male and female, then

```
barplot(table(male_response))
barplot(table(female_response))
```